# Prove that $\operatorname{det}A = \lambda_1 \dots \lambda_n.$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$-matrix, with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_n.$ Prove that $$\operatorname{det}A = \lambda_1 \dots \lambda_n.$$

**My thoughts:**

I know that the eigenvalues will give us an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues being the diagonal entries but I do not know how can I prove this. Also I know that the determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of its diagonal entries but I do not know how to prove this either.

Could someone help me in solving this exercise please?

Comment: The eigenvalues are the roots of which polynomial? (Then their product has something to do with the free coefficient, Vieta.)

Comment: Express $A$ in terms of a basis of eigenvectors

Comment: they are the roots of the characteristic polynomial @dan_fulea but I do not know the relation between their products and the free coefficient ..... could you explain to me more details please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$-matrix, with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_n.$

$$P(\lambda)=\operatorname{det}(A - \lambda  I_n)= (\lambda_1 - \lambda)(\lambda_2 - \lambda)  \dots (\lambda_n - \lambda).$$
$$\operatorname{det}(A)=P(0)=  \operatorname{det}(A - 0I_n)=(\lambda_1 - 0)(\lambda_2 - 0)  \dots (\lambda_n - 0)= \lambda_1 \dots \lambda_n$$

If $\lambda$ = $0$, $\lambda  I_n = O$, where $O$ is a null matrix.
Then $A - 0I_n$=$A-O$=$A$

Comment: I do not understand why $\operatorname{det} A = P(0),$ could you please explain this?

Comment: If $\lambda$ = $0$, $\lambda  I_n = O$, where $O$ is a null matrix.
Then $A - 0I_n$=$A-O$=$A$

Comment: does not the determinant is expanded in terms of, say, the first row? should not there be some negative signs?

Comment: Do you know the signs of eigenvalues?

Comment: I do not understand you, could you clarify please?